# Content is not visible in CodeIgniter calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar, phpmyadmin

I can insert data into the database using CodeIgniter and also get the data from the database, but the problem is I can't get the data from date 1-9 (the data is present in the database). After the 9th of the month, the data is retrieved successfully.

**Controller:**

```
function display($year=null,$month=null){
    if (!$year) {
        $year = date('Y');
    }
    if (!$month) {
        $month = date('m');
    }

    $this->load->model('Calendar_model');

    if ($day = $this->input->post('day')) {
        $this->Calendar_model->add_calendar_data("$year-$month-$day",$this->input->post('data')
        );
    }

    $this->load->model('calendar_model');
    $data['calendar']=$this->calendar_model->generate($year,$month);
    $data['viewName']=('Student/s_calendar');
    $this->load->view('Student/template',$data);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function get_cal_data($year,$month){
    $query=$this->db->select('date,data')->from('student_calender')->like('date',"$year-$month")->get();
    $cal_data=array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $cal_data[substr($row->date,8,2)]=$row->data;
    }
    return $cal_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function for your calendar data the codeignitor only picks values past 9 because it compares the two characters in the html page to the two characters of days from your database. any number below 10 does not match because in your database it saves any day below 10 with a zero. use this

```
function get_calender_data($year,$month)
{

    $query = $this->db->select('date, data')->from('calendar')
->like('date',"$year-$month",'after')->get();

    $cal_data = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if(substr($row->date,8,1)==0)
        {
            $cal_data[substr($row->date,9,1)] = $row->data;
        }
        else{
        $cal_data[substr($row->date,8,2)] = $row->data;
        }
    }
    return $cal_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem via zend framework finally I got the point that the data in mysql is in this format :

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss
```

And my query was in this format :

```
YYYY-m-d h:i:s
```

It means for example I hade

```
2013-01-02 13:02:30
```

in database and I searched for time between

```
2013-1-2 13:2:30 and 2013-1-3 13:2:30
```

which gave me wrong answers.
use vardump and see your values of year and month!

Comment: http://rahatprojects.hostei.com/Main/index.php/Student/Mycal/display visit this link and see the actual problem..in the upper site i just tested that the data is present on the db..